# can anybody guide me how the instagram application created the view of login and tabbar in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, instagram

hi can any body guide me how to display the login screen like [instagram](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8) , [pinterest](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pinterest/id429047995?mt=8)
and other social networking app like [picyou](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/picyou-share-photos-free-camera/id492468784?mt=8) they show login screen like this

before login and after login

[image: before login] [image: after login] i think this are two different view or just they have just changed the tabbar and the navigation bar?

Comment: @All anybody can help me? how to implement like this.

Answer (score 0):

The first is a UIView with 2 buttons, the second is a customized tabbar (probably made by 5 UIButtons in a UIView).

When you are not logged, the second tab isHidden and when you are logged the first tab isHidden.